# Creating REST API

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm creating my first API. 
I need to create, modify, get and delete two kinds of things: users, dogs (for example). Dogs depends on users. So:

- GET "/users/12/dogs" (get list of dogs of user #12)
- GET "/users/12/dogs/2" (get the dog # 2 of user # 12)
- DELETE "/users/12" (delete user # 12)
- POST "/users/12/dogs" (create new dog for user # 12)

etc..

I dont know what to do on backend. I'm figuring to make REST API on plain PHP (or using Laravel). As I understand - I have to make file (for example api.php) and listen there to requests, do something with db and make a response back to frontend. But if I call "/users/12/dogs" with GET request, how my server should know, that this data for API. The path of API file is "/api.php", but I call "/users/12/dogs", how this request redirects to "api.php"? Or how it should works?

Second question is: how many files of API should I have? Is it good to put all API requests listeners (for both "/users/" and "users/1/dogs/12") in one file,

Of course before asking this question I googled and read some about it. There are many information about four main requests, about URLs, about "easy REST API" frameworks, about REST API realization in common. But nowhere about details of realization..

Answer my questions, please or give some links to good detailed description of REST API realization on PHP.

Comment: Honestly? What kind of magical answer are you expecting? This is such a large, open-ended question it’s unfathomable. Did you bother to Google “creating a REST API with PHP”? There must be hundreds of articles and tutorials showing you have.

Comment: I expected such answers as yours. But at least question "how this request redirects to "api.php"" can be answered shortly i suppose.

Comment: There is no ‘redirecting to api.php’. An API is just like a web site, but responses are returned as JSON or XML strings rather than HTML views, and more often interacted with programmatically than with a web browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try using slim framework  (http://www.slimframework.com/)

1. it's done using URL rewriting (mod_rewrite in apache)
2. you can use as many files as you like or just 1

Comment: I'm really Sorry, I miss-clicked and accidentially downvoted your answer. I can't undo this until you make some minor changes to your post. If you edit something I will directly change my vote to up. Sorry again!

Comment: upvoted, sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a framework for this, as it makes things a lot easier for you. It also provides you with a basic infrastructure that will help you to get along with all your questions.

There are various PHP frameworks out there, that can help you: Just take a look at [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), [Recess](http://www.recessframework.org/) or [FRAPI](http://getfrapi.com/) for example.

In your case I would go with the Slim Framework, which is a php micro framework that will help you to quickly write simple RESTful web applications and APIs. It provides you with all the basic features you'll need to develop a RESTful API (i.e. routing, templating).

I made a little sample application using the Slim Framework some time ago. You can find the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/KlickReform/weblab/tree/master/rest/slim-framework). This may help you get started.